# Scan type of DFT calculations adding Freq=Raman keyword

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, raman

I´m doing a scan calculation by adding Freq=Raman keyword. My objective is to obtain the Raman spectrum of each conformation in my compound. However, when i write the Freq=Raman Keyword, only the Raman spectrum of the last conformation in the scan is calculated . How can i solve this problem?
Thanks!